# Process a directory of images in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, io, jpeg

Is there a way to read in and process a large directory of images in such a way that I can process one image at a time, and then once one is done, it will retrieve the next image from the directory, until it's gone through the whole directory?

I have a large folder of jpeg files, and I want to import them one at a time, alphabetically, analyze them, get an output, and then move on to the next file in the folder. Any help is much appreciated.

Sorry for the lack of eloquence. I've been going at this for about 10 hours straight at this point.

Comment: Do you have something that you tried?  Any code we can give feedback or pointers on?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I have all the code in place (aside from the file access), I just don't know how to access a directory on my computer from XCode and read in the files sequentially.